# Why Basic Authentication is not working in C# web api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have written code to implement basic authentication in my project in C# asp.net framework, but it is not working.
It is not asking for authentication while calling this web-api, It should show 401 (unauthorised) without authentication request header, But is giving the result.

Here are the code which I have written. Please let me know what I am missing.

BasicAuthenticationAttribute.cs

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if(actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        else
        {
            string authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            string decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
            string[] usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
            string username = usernamePasswordArray[0];
            string password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

            if(EmployeeSecurity.Login(username, password))
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), null);
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeSecurity.cs

```
namespace OfficeTest
{
    public class EmployeeSecurity
    {
        public static bool Login(string username, string password)
        {
            using(EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
            {
                return entities.Users.Any(u => u.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && u.Password.Equals(password));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

        config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
        // To restrict access for every Web API controller globally

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

OfficeController.cs

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public class OfficeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDataRepository<Employee> _dataRepository;
    public OfficeController(IDataRepository<Employee> dataRepository)
    {
        _dataRepository = dataRepository;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {
        return _dataRepository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Note: **public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)** is not being called.
And my endpoint is "https://localhost:44309/api/Office"

My response is:

```
<ArrayOfEmployee xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EmployeeDataAccess">
<Employee>
<DOB>2002-02-02T00:00:00</DOB>
<department>Developer</department>
<empId>1</empId>
<firstName>Ainuddin</firstName>
<lastName>Khan</lastName>
<mobile>78349827953</mobile>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<DOB>2012-12-12T00:00:00</DOB>
<department>Analyst</department>
<empId>2</empId>
<firstName>Vishal</firstName>
<lastName>Maurya</lastName>
<mobile>783423827953</mobile>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<DOB>2002-02-02T00:00:00</DOB>
<department>Developer</department>
<empId>4</empId>
<firstName>Akbar</firstName>
<lastName>Khan</lastName>
<mobile>7825954</mobile>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<DOB>2002-02-02T00:00:00</DOB>
<department>Developer</department>
<empId>5</empId>
<firstName>Aslam</firstName>
<lastName>Khan</lastName>
<mobile>7828765954</mobile>
</Employee>
</ArrayOfEmployee>
```

Comment: my endpoint is "https:  //localhost:44309/api/Office"

Comment: The response contains headers and a body.  The status 401 is in the header.  It looks like your response has a body which is the Employee.  When an error occurs you are not getting in the body an Employee instead an error message.  Not sure from your posting what issue you are trying to resolve.  1) Are you getting an employee in the body? 2) Are you getting an error in the body? 3) Is server sending a response when failing authentication.  Maybe an error is being returned and you thing it is an Employee.  Can you give more details.  I'm trying to help.

Comment: @jdweng server is sending a response when failing authentication

Comment: Yes.  The response has status code of 401.  What else does it contain?  Does it contain a real employee data, just more details on the error, or an empty body and just the 401 status in the header?  Is the issue the server code sending back data (not just the status code) after failing the authentication?  What need to be fixed 1) The client request is bad 2) The server sending back the wrong response 3) Or the client controller processing of the 401 status.

Comment: @jdweng there is no problem in response, only authentication is not working. Method "OnAuthorization" is not being called.

Comment: It looks like code is in Server that reads the request and create a response.  Error 401 is Unauthorized so : actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null. I don't know how the authentication is achieved.  1) it could be a parameter in the URL 2) It could be an HTTP header 3) It could be a cookie.  Do you have the code that produces a good response?  When a failure occurs there should not be a good response.  For some reason when 401 occurs the code is still reaching the good response.

Comment: @jdweng I have put breakpoint at line "if(actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)" and running the code in debug mode. this line is not getting executed

Comment: You also get it here(actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);), but it just filling the status code in the header.  Something else could be adding data to the body which is the Employee.

Comment: @jdweng Anyway, the method OnAuthorization is not being called.

Comment: Are you getting a response with an employee data?  I need to know if any of your code is being executed on the server.  The 401 could be added by software that is not yours.  If you are getting employee data than your code is being executed.  Then you need to find out why in your code the OnAuthoriztion is not being called.  The failure could be in the base class AuthorizationFilterAttribute.  If none of your code is being executed than we need to look at Roles to see why the client is being blocked.